# "Toggle state"-variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, toggle, state

I'm trying to set a variable (currentState) with a boolean but it doesn't seem like the variable is recognized within the conditionals. What am I missing?

```
function toggle(customID) { // Function set on button, 'customID' is the ID
                            // of element to toggle with button. Ex:
                            // <button onclick="(toggle('menu')">Button</button>
    var theToggledElement = document.getElementById(customID);
    var currentState = false; // false = hidden. true = visible.

    if (currentState === false) {
        currentState = true;
        theToggledElement.style.left = '0px';
        console.log('State set to "visible" and left to "0px"');
    }
    else if (currentState === true) {
        currentState = false;
        theToggledElement.style.left = 'calc(-100% + (0.5cm + 1.461544602cm + .5cm))';
        console.log('State set to "hidden" and left to "calc(-100% + (0.5cm + 1.461544602cm + .5cm))"')
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Every time you call the function the variable starts out as `false`. If you want it to remember the state between calls, it needs to be declared outside the function.

Comment: If you need to have different state for different elements, you should save the state in an element property, not a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar thank you! Moved the "currentState" var outside like this:

```
var currentState = false; // false = hidden. true = visible.
function toggle(customID) { // Function set on button, 'customID' is the ID
                            // of element to toggle with button. Ex:
                            // <button onclick="(toggle('menu')">Button</button>
    var theToggledElement = document.getElementById(customID);

    if (currentState === false) {
        currentState = true;
        theToggledElement.style.left = '0px';
        console.log('State set to "visible" and left to "0px"');
    }
    else if (currentState === true) {
        currentState = false;
        theToggledElement.style.left = 'calc(-100% + (0.5cm + 1.461544602cm + .5cm))';
        console.log('State set to "hidden" and left to "calc(-100% + (0.5cm + 1.461544602cm + .5cm))"')
    }
}
```